# Unable to use ls command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, alias

While using VirtualBox, I'm unable to use the `ls` command, it shows

```
ls: unrecognized option '--color=auto'
ls: use the --help option for usage information
```

Can anybody give me suggestion?

I searched google and came through the `alias` command where it shows

```
alias cp='cp -i'
alias dmesgg='dmesg | grep'
alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
alias lh='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lh'
alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
alias lt='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lht'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias pss='ps -ef | grep'
alias rm='rm -i'
```

Please provide any suggestion for it.

Comment: I'd say look in your .bashrc or .profile file for lines containing `--color=auto`, and look for signs of bad formatting, but that trailing `<br/>` has me wondering where you could possibly be getting that value. what do you get when you run `echo $LS_OPTIONS`?

Comment: Sorry that was copy paste error. I use echo $LS_OPTIONS it shows this message : **[1] 2318   bash:LS_OPTIONS: command not found  [1]+  Done       echo**

Answer (score 2):

First run `unalias ls`. Then run `ls` as normal.

You will have to do that every time you start a new shell unless you find where the bad alias is being created, e.g. in `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` as described by @dirkt above, or perhaps in `~/.bashrc`. Alternatively you can add `unalias ls` to the end of your `~/.profile`, though that is a pretty nasty hack.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a misconfigured `.profile` or similar file. (see the `man` command for your shell, there's a bunch of them. If you don't know which shell you have, use `ps`.) which either sets the option wrongly as `'--color=auto'<br/>` (if this is not a cut and paste error) using an alias similar to the ones you googled, or you have an `ls` command that does not unterstand this option.

To make `ls` work, try calling it directly as `/bin/ls`. If it's not in `/bin`, try `which ls` to find out where it is.

With the working `ls` command, look at the various shell-profile files, and fix the problem.

Comment: I search for ls by bin, the path /bin/ls is there but when i typed **which ls** it showed **/usr/bin/ls**

Comment: ps commands showed me this output 
**PID TTY          TIME CMD    1996 tty1     00:00:00 login     2020 tty1     00:00:00 bash        2269 tty1     00:00:00 bash    2332 tty1     00:00:00 ps  **

Comment: You have a `bash`, so the files are `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` (at least on my system).  The tilde `~` means your home directory. Read `man bash` for details (long, use the search function). If on your system it's `/usr/bin/ls`, then use that.

Comment: i used **!/bin/ls** command it showed me ***ls (GNU coreutils) 5.97
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Richard Stallman and David MacKenzie.***

Answer (score 0):

To use `ls` *temporarily* without `unalias`ing it simply run `\ls` or `command ls`

To fix the root cause permanently you'll need to [find where the alias was defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58224674/995714). Run

```
bash -ixlc : 2>&1 | grep -w ls
```

and it'll show the actual `alias` command that was run on shell start up. Then you can grep for that string to find the file and edit it, or you can also run `bash -ixlc : 2>&1 | grep -P '^\++ (\.|source)\s'` to list the files that were sourced and edit the alias definitions in them

Or simply run

```
bash -ixlc : 2>&1 | grep -P '\bls\b|^\++ (\.|source)\s'
```

and it'll show the source file following by the alias(es) in that file